# larval images files available at different paths in local and production mode

Tags: php, laravel

I'm not able to figure our how the asset and url helpers work in laravel. I'm writing a MediaLibrary with ReactJs and Laravel.

When the images are uploaded I store them under `storage/app/public` which is symlinked to `public` directory too

`php artisan storage:link`

now When I fetch these images in the media library

```
public function index()
{
    $allFiles = Storage::disk('public')->allFiles('images');
    $files    = [];
    foreach ($allFiles as $file) {
        \array_push(
            $files,
            [
                "name" => \basename($file),
                "url"  => asset($file),
            ]
        );
    }
    return response()->json($files)->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

this works in the development, local mode but gives a 404 error for the images in production. Where as

```
public function index()
{
    $allFiles = Storage::disk('public')->allFiles('images');
    $files    = [];
    foreach ($allFiles as $file) {
        \array_push(
            $files,
            [
                "name" => \basename($file),
                "url"  => asset(Storage::url($file)),
            ]
        );
    }
    return response()->json($files)->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

this works in both local and production.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: give permission your image file in production mode.

Comment: that I have, has nothing to do with this problem IMO, it runs under nginx and all directories are under www-data user and group

Comment: Can you please verify if you have created symbolic link or not, refer create a symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public